# Intermittent MySQL Connection Error in Azure Website

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

I'm getting the following error intermittently when making a call from my ASP.Net MVC web application which is using Dapper to query MySQL.

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

The exception *only* occurs when my web app is published to Azure. It has worked 100% of the time when I run the code locally. I've deployed the code to a second azure website, and also get the exception there, again intermittently.

The MySQL database is running on an Azure VM (Ubuntu). This server also has some R scripts that access the database, which are being run at a set interval. I've had no connectivity issue with these either. It is just the .Net code that's struggling.

I've scoured the web, but don't feel like I've turned up anything of value. Most of the links have pointed to a connection string problem, but since it works intermittently that doesn't seem to fit my problem. Some links have referenced DNS issues, but I'm getting the same problem when I use the IP Address instead of the machine name for the DNS server.

I'm sure I need to track down more information, but I'm not sure where it would be. This is my first foray into using a MySQL db in this fashion, and I'm not familiar with config options or log files on that side of things. I feel similarly about Azure websites with database interactions too.

What can I try next?

*Just to drive home the point about this error being intermittent, here's a screenshot from the Runscope job that's hitting the page (thus triggering the MySQL query) every 5 minutes:*

[image]

Comment: SQL Server had a similar issue which they called a "transient connection issue" on Azure. It was common enough that the latest version of Entity Framework implemented special retry logic to handle the problem. Not sure if it's the same but your best bet is probably to add some retry w/ backoff logic to your connection manager.

Comment: Thanks for sharing... that was not something I'd heard about. I sincerely hope that my issue is different than that though. The time it would take to retry until a successful response would make the website totally unusable. If it comes to that then I'll need to find a different hosting solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix (or perhaps "circumvent") this problem by adding the `--skip-host-cache` flag to our mysql configuration file. I still don't fully understand what the root of the problem is, but we haven't had any issues with MySQL connectivity from the Azure website since adding that.